# Qualitative solutions of KDV

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, soliton-theory

I'm reading *Solitons: An introduction* [[1]](https://books.google.fr/books?id=HPmbIDk2u-gC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false), and in the chapter two (§2.2 p. 21), the author make a qualitative analysis of KDV: $u_t -6uu_x + u_{xxx} = 0$, then he try find solutions on this form $u(x,t)=f(x-ct)$, and then make the following substitution $\xi =x-ct$ and then we have: $-cf'-6ff'+f'''=0$, integrating twice we have:

> $$\frac{1}{2}(f')^2 = f^3 + \frac{1}{2}c f^2 + Af +B \equiv F(f)$$

where $A$ and $B$ are constants.

So I don't understand this step (cf. book [1] p. 23). He wrote the Taylor series for $F(f)$ around $f_1$, where $f(\xi_1) = f_1$ and $F(f_1) = 0$

> $$(f')^2 = 2(f-f_1)F'(f_1) + O((f-f_1)^2)) \tag{1}$$

And then:

> $$f = f_1 + \frac{1}{2}(\xi - \xi_1)^2F'(f_1) + O((\xi - \xi_1)^4) \tag{2}$$

I did not understand what he did in p. 23 from $(\text{1})$ to $(\text{2})$, someone can explain to me?

---

[[1]](https://books.google.fr/books?id=HPmbIDk2u-gC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false) P.G. Drazin, R.S. Johnson, *Solitons: An Introduction*, Cambridge University Press, 1989

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form of your equation can be thought of as an energy conservation law, with $K = (f')^2$ as kinetic energy, $U = -F(f)$ as potential energy and $$K+U = E$$ forms the energy of the system.

Since your $F(f)$ is a cubic polynomial, the zeros of the polynomial correspond to $0$ energy. i.e. $f' =0 $. Perhaps Newton-Raphson method is used to "iteratively" converge to their solution.

Comment: You don't need to iteratively converge to the solution, you can do it by direct integration. The shape of the cubic is just to see where the physically meaningful solutions must lie in relation to the zeros.